# Asp.net Application Security

Tags: asp.net, security

My firm is planing to develop an online banking system in `asp.net/c#`.As we have not yet started yet , i thought it would be nice if i could get some suggestions from you guys.
First of all , 
Security ,, How should we get `SSL` Certificate for my application ,,, is it provided by people who will host our website. 
Secondly ,, our requirement is such that for example , if a user is looged in, he should just be able to use the application in the new tab or new instance of the browser and not in browser of different type ,,, how do we achieve this. I guess Forms authentication and session  will solve our problem or is there something additional.
Any suggestions will be really helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read more about creating secure ASP.Net website in the below link

[Design and Deploy Secure Web Apps with ASP.NET 2.0 and IIS 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163702.aspx)